# Unable to create a vue-web-extension from vue-cli

Tags: vue.js, google-chrome-extension, vue-cli, webextension-polyfill

Currently, I am modifying a chrome extension I have built to adding a popup page that is developed in Vue. I am using this tutorial, https://www.streaver.com/blog/posts/create-web-extension-vue.html.

Whenever I try the step `vue init kocal/vue-web-extension my-extension`, I get the following error:

`vue-cli · ENOENT: no such file or directory, scandir '/Users/avidave/.vue-templates/kocal-vue-web-extension/template'`

I have updated my vue-cli to the latest version so I am not sure what this really means. I know the file template doesn't exist, but I am not sure what is the right way to create the file in the kocal-vue-web-extension, or if it is needed for that matter.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try This

```
vue create --preset kocal/vue-web-extension my-extension
```

Comment: Thank you, finally worked! I didn't get a chance to check out kocal/vue-web-extension Github but the same command is stated in the instructions there https://github.com/Kocal/vue-web-extension